# form control click not responding

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a checkbox form control that I want to execute the code below based on a true or false status. If true (checked) then filter the dates, if false (not checked) then remove the filter. I don't know what is wrong but it is not executing the filter commands.

```
Sub CheckBox5_Click()
Dim StDate As Long
Dim EndDate As Long
StDate = ActiveSheet.Range("T2")
EndDate = ActiveSheet.Range("T1")

If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 5").ControlFormat.Value = True Then Range("b37:r10000").AutoFilter 
2, ">=" & StDate, xlAnd, "<=" & EndDate
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 5").ControlFormat.Value = False Then ActiveSheet.Range("B36:r10000").AutoFilter Field:=2 'Range("$b$37:$r$10000").AutoFilter 2
End Sub
```

Comment: Please specify whether `ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 5").ControlFormat.Value` returns `true` and `false` correctly with respect to the checking of the checkbox (do debugging). If that is working fine, then I suggest you use the macro record function in Excel, that should allow you to record the code corresponding to your activation of the filter through the GUI: you just hit 'record', with the mouse do the relevant things (clicks) to activate the filter, and finally hit the 'stop' button to stop the recording. After that, look at the auto-generated code: you'll get clues as to the right code.

Comment: I am not an expert programmer but I used the immediate window and typed this in          ?ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 5").ControlFormat.Value
and the value it returned was "-4146 ", what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, run that command in the immediate window, when the checkbox is checked, and then again when the checkbox is unchecked. Report back what values are displayed.

Comment: When checked the value returns "1", when unchecked the value returns "-4146"

Comment: I changed the code as follows and it works: If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 5").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then Range("b37:r10000").AutoFilter 2, ">=" & StDate, xlAnd, "<=" & EndDate
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 5").ControlFormat.Value = -4146 Then ActiveSheet.Range("B36:r10000").AutoFilter Field:=2 'Range("$b$37:$r$10000").AutoFilter 2
not sure why though

Comment: I'm not sure either. Sometimes with boolean variables ('true'-'false' variables), because 8 bits (a byte) (a 'true'-'false' variable can actually be stored in just one bit) are used for their storage using a particular encoding format, the conversion to an integer doesn't convert to a straight 0 or 1. I'm guessing that maybe the checkbox is tri-state (can have three different values), and the -4146 corresponds to the conversion of one of the states to a rather non-intuitive integer.

Comment: will it always return that way? do I need to worry about it ever returning something other than "1" or "-4146"?

Comment: And last question, I am using helper cells for the start and end dates and was wondering if I can incorporate vba code so i can get rid of the helper cells? for start date of current year I am using a cell with formula =DATE(YEAR(T1),1,1), for end date of current year I am using formula TODAY(). For start date of previous year I am using =DATE(YEAR(T1),1,1)-365 and for last day of previous year I am using =DATE(YEAR(T1),1,1)-1

Comment: Hopefully the value mapping will stay the same. To be honest, when I noticed that the property you were using was called `ControlFormat`, I thought you were probably using the wrong property. But then you said you managed to get it to work... You might want to look at the official VBA docs (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba). I haven't read their terms and conditions yet, so not using it today. Have no Excel today, so can't test code out on any of my machines.

Instead of helper cells, you could use the VBA function `inputbox`, which will create a dialogue prompting for text input.

Comment: Ok thanks, well I'd like to mark this as answered but don't see that option.

Comment: You can only do that when an answer has been provided. We have just been discussing the problem in comments. What you can do, is write an answer based on your investigations and comments. Then you can probably press on the 'accept answer' function/button to accept your own answer to the problem.